# Stemming with R Text Analysis

Tags: r, text, tm, stemming

I am doing a lot of analysis with the `TM` package. One of my biggest problems are related to stemming and stemming-like transformations.

Let's say I have several accounting related terms (I am aware of the spelling issues).
After stemming we have:

```
accounts   -> account  
account    -> account  
accounting -> account  
acounting  -> acount  
acount     -> acount  
acounts    -> acount  
accounnt   -> accounnt
```

**Result**: 3 Terms (account, acount, account) where I would have liked 1 (account) as all these relate to the same term.

**1)** To correct spelling is a possibility, but I have never attempted that in R. Is that even possible?

**2)** The other option is to make a reference list i.e. account = (accounts, account, accounting, acounting, acount, acounts, accounnt) and then replace all occurrences with the master term. How would I do this in R?

Once again, any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We could set up a list of synonyms and replace those values. For example

```
synonyms <- list(
    list(word="account", syns=c("acount", "accounnt"))
)
```

This says we want to replace "acount" and "accounnt" with "account" (i'm assuming we're doing this after stemming). Now let's create test data.

```
raw<-c("accounts", "account", "accounting", "acounting", 
     "acount", "acounts", "accounnt")
```

And now let's define a transformation function that will replace the words in our list with the primary synonym.

```
library(tm)
replaceSynonyms <- content_transformer(function(x, syn=NULL) { 
    Reduce(function(a,b) {
        gsub(paste0("\\b(", paste(b$syns, collapse="|"),")\\b"), b$word, a)}, syn, x)   
})
```

Here we use the `content_transformer` function to define a custom transformation. And basically we just do a `gsub` to replace each of the words. We can then use this on a corpus

```
tm <- Corpus(VectorSource(raw))
tm <- tm_map(tm, stemDocument)
tm <- tm_map(tm, replaceSynonyms, synonyms)
inspect(tm)
```

and we can see all these values are transformed into "account" as desired. To add other synonyms, just add additional lists to the main `synonyms` list. Each sub-list should have the names "word" and "syns".

Comment: Great, this should work for me, but I have to compile the lists manually - which is OK. Much more control than before. Thanks!

Comment: Just tested this on my live data - Works like a charm! The hard part is to first of all identify all the word variants and then somehow make the list building part easier/automated.

Answer (score 8):

Mr. Flick has answered question #2.  I am approaching via answering question #1.

Here is an approach the uses a binary search of a known word data base (`DICTIONARY` from `qdapDictionaries`).  A binary lookup is slow for sure but if we make some assumptions about the replacing (like a range of differences in number of character).  So here's the basic idea:

1. Turn the `Corpus` into a unique bag of words using `qdap`'s `bag_o_words`
2. Look those words up in a dictionary (`qdapDictionaries`' `DICTIONARY` data set) to find words not recognize using `match`

   - These `misses` from step # 2 will be what we lookup
3. Determine number of characters for words in a dictionary to eliminate gross difference later using `nchar`
4. Run each element of `misses` through a loop (`sapply`) and do the following:
   a. stem each element from `misses` using `tm::stemDocument`
   b. determine number of characters and eliminate those from dictionary that are not within that range using `nchar`
   c. use `agrep` with a `max.distance` to eliminate more words from the dictionary
   d. use a binary lookup (that reverse engineers `agrep`) to determine the word from dictionary that is closest to the missed element [note this is a non-exported function from `qdap` called `qdap:::Ldist`]
5. The result is a named vector that we can use for `gsub`bing
6. Use `tm_map` with a custom `tm` flavored `gsub` function to replace words
7. Do the stemming with `tm_map` and `stemDocument`

Here's the code.  I made a fake `Corpus` using the words you provide and some random words to demonstrate how to do this from start to end.  You can play with `range` and `max.distance` that is supplied to `sapply`.  The looser you are with these the slower the search will be but tightiening these too much will make it more likely to make a mistake.  This really isn't an answer for spelling correction in a  general sense but works here because you were stemming anyway.  There's an [`Aspell`](http://www.omegahat.org/Aspell/) package but I have never used it before.

```
terms <- c("accounts", "account", "accounting", "acounting", "acount", "acounts", "accounnt")

library(tm); library(qdap)

fake_text <- unlist(lapply(terms, function(x) {
    paste(sample(c(x, sample(DICTIONARY[[1]], sample(1:5, 1)))), collapse=" ")
}))

fake_text

myCorp <- Corpus(VectorSource(fake_text))
terms2 <- unique(bag_o_words(as.data.frame(myCorp)[[2]]))
misses <- terms2[is.na(match(terms2, DICTIONARY[[1]]))]

chars <- nchar(DICTIONARY[[1]])

replacements <- sapply(misses, function(x, range = 3, max.distance = .2) {
    x <- stemDocument(x)
    wchar <- nchar(x)
    dict <- DICTIONARY[[1]][chars >= (wchar - range) & chars <= (wchar + range)]
    dict <- dict[agrep(x, dict, max.distance=max.distance)]
    names(which.min(sapply(dict, qdap:::Ldist, x)))
})

replacer <- content_transformer(function(x) { 
    mgsub(names(replacements), replacements, x, ignore.case = FALSE, fixed = FALSE)
})

myCorp <- tm_map(myCorp, replacer)
inspect(myCorp <- tm_map(myCorp, stemDocument))
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler, for now I think it is easier for me to use MrFlick's solution as I have much more control over it, BUT you have put me onto a few ideas and packages to explore, thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 8):

This question inspired me to attempt to write a spell check for the `qdap` package.  There's an interactive version that may be useful here.  It's available in `qdap >= version 2.1.1`.  That means you'll need the dev version at the moment..  here are the steps to install:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("qdapDictionaries", "trinker")
install_github("qdap", "trinker")
library(tm); library(qdap)
```

**## Recreate a `Corpus` like you describe.**

```
terms <- c("accounts", "account", "accounting", "acounting", "acount", "acounts", "accounnt")

fake_text <- unlist(lapply(terms, function(x) {
    paste(sample(c(x, sample(DICTIONARY[[1]], sample(1:5, 1)))), collapse=" ")
}))

fake_text

inspect(myCorp <- Corpus(VectorSource(fake_text)))
```

**## The interactive spell checker (`check_spelling_interactive`)**

```
m <- check_spelling_interactive(as.data.frame(myCorp)[[2]])
preprocessed(m)
inspect(myCorp <- tm_map(myCorp, correct(m)))
```

The `correct` function merely grabs a closure function from the output of `check_spelling_interactive` and allows you to then apply the "correcting" to any new text string(s).