# r text analysis stem completion

Tags: r, text, tm, stemming

How to complete words after stemming in R?

```
x <- c("completed","complete","completion","teach","taught")
tm <- Corpus(VectorSource(x))
tm <- tm_map(tm, stemDocument)
inspect(tm)
```

Example for illustration purpose as the actual text corpus is much bigger.

I've searched for earlier [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443388/stemming-with-r-text-analysis) which points to creating a set of synonyms, but for large corpus, how is it possible to get such as synonym dictionary? For verbs how can I complete stemmed words to current tense? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TM has a function `stemCompletion()`

```
x <- c("completed","complete","completion","teach","taught")
tm <- Corpus(VectorSource(x))
tm <- tm_map(tm, stemDocument)
inspect(tm)
dictCorpus <- tm
tm <- tm_map(tm, stemDocument)
tm <- tm_map(tm, stripWhitespace, mc.cores=cores)  

tm<-tm_map(tm, stemCompletion,dictionary=dictCorpus)
```

As for completing verbs to the present tense, I am not sure that is possible with tm. Maybe RWeka, word2vec or qdap will have methods but I am not sure.

A quick and dirty, solution may be to set `type = shortest` in `stemDocument` generally I think current tense words will be shorter than past tense and gerunds.